# Angular and FlickrAPI cross-origin error

Tags: angularjs, flickr

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error when I run these API requests?

Error: 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

```
photographyServices.factory('Flickr', function($http, $resource, $q, appAlert,    flickrConfig) {    
  return {
    myFaves: function() {
      var flickrUrl = $resource('https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/', 
      { method: 'flickr.photos.search', api_key: flickrConfig.apiKey, user_id: flickrConfig.myId, sort: 'date-taken-desc',
        extras: 'description, url_c, date_taken', format: 'json', jsoncallback: 'JSON_CALLBACK' }, 
      { 'load': { 'method': 'JSONP' } });
      var q = $q.defer();
      flickrUrl.load({
        tags: 'fave'
      }, function(resp) {
        q.resolve(resp);
      }, function(err) {
        q.reject(err);
      })

      return q.promise;
    },

    myGalleries: function() {
      var flickrUrl = $resource('https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/', 
      { method: 'flickr.photosets.getList', api_key: flickrConfig.apiKey, user_id: flickrConfig.myId,
        format: 'json', jsoncallback: 'JSON_CALLBACK' }, 
      { 'load': { 'method': 'JSONP' } });
      var q = $q.defer();
      flickrUrl.load({
      }, function(resp) {
        q.resolve(resp);
      }, function(err) {
        q.reject(err);
      })

      return q.promise; 
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: may be try only http instead of https

Comment: Hmm. Nope. Same error.